# AppBar appears where it shouldn't?

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I have an android app with two activities `main` and `secondary`.

`main` activity has following lines in its `XML`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

`secondary` activity doesnt have `appbar` mentioned in its layout file,
and yet when I invoke second activity from first - I can still see `AppBar` appearing on top of the screen..

is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing the AppBar and the Actionbar?

Comment: Are you using a ".NoActionBar" theme for the second activity? Otherwise you'll still see an action bar even if you haven't specified one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be in your theme xml.
Try to define the ".NoActionBar" theme in the "values/styles.xml" for example to "@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

Another way is to define the theme of activity in AndroidManifest